# Exception Autowiring Service interface in controller class

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I and trying to autowire a service interface in the controller but i am getting an error, please help. Codes below :

**Exception**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'todoComponentController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service.component.TodoCS com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service.rest.controller.TodoComponentController.tocs; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service.component.TodoCS] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

**Controller class**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping ("/todo")
public class TodoComponentController extends BaseController {
    private static Logger _LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TodoComponentController.class); 

    @Autowired TodoCS tocs;

     @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public create() {
            return null;
        }
}
```

**Service Interface**

```
@Service
public interface TodoCS extends ComponentService {

}
```

**XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd        
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd"
        >

    <context:annotation-config />   

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service, com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.cbo.mapper, com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.bo.project.mapper"/> 

</beans>
```

Comment: where is implementation of the `TodoCS` interface? Who will implement it for you?

Comment: Sorry, I have also implemented the same in a class which is an abstract, code below :

Comment: can you create an object of abstract class? It's same as interface. You need a concrete class so that spring can plug it.

Comment: public abstract class TodoCSImpl extends BaseCSImpl implements TodoCS {}

Comment: I believe putting @Component will not make much difference, because you cant instantiate an abstract class, Right?

Comment: yes you are right. remove abstract and use @Component to auto-detect bean for wiring.

Comment: I cant remove abstract its required there, any other solution ?

Comment: Create one more class extending this abstract class. In the last you need a concrete class.

Answer (score 1):

You have to annotate the implementation of `TodoCS` Not the interface itself.

```
@Service
public class TodoCSImpl implements TodoCS {

}
```

Then you can autowire the class.

Answer (score 0):

You need a class which implements `TodoCS` interface. Then, annotation the implementation class with `@Component` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

Spring, at time of context initialization is trying to search a bean name TodoCS in package : com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service.**component**.TodoCS.

And in configuartion file you mentioned package name as : com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service. Try adding com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service.component.TodoCS in base package scan as below:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service, com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.cbo.mapper, com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.bo.project.mapper,com.rapidinstinct.avia.plat.service.component"/>
```

Comment: Okay, there are three levels of interfaces in here, 3 is extending 2 and again 2, is extending 1. Here i have placed the code to scan interface 1 which will automatically be instantiated.

Comment: As interface can't be instantiated, try scanning of interface 3 in your case.